# force ie8 standard browser mode view even if user selects IE8 Compat View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags

I am using the below meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This is my full html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=edge” /> 
    <title>Compatability Mode?</title>
</head>
<body style="padding:50px;">

    <div style="border:1px solid green;padding:30px;">
        <div style="position:relative; left:-30px">
            <div style="position:absolute;height:20px;width:20px;background:red;left:inherit"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        If the red box is outside the line, it's ie8 mode<br />
        If the red box is inside the line, it's ie7 mode<br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now what i want to achieve is, if the user goes to `browser mode` and changes it to `IE8 Compat View` or if `IE8 Compat view` is defaulted in `compatibility view settings`, i want the page to be rendered in IE8 mode only
How can i do that?

I am ok with any solution(javascript,jquery) or anything else

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

By design, the user (or admin) is fully in control of the experience and can do many things to view your design in unexpected ways.  You know about the CV button (which actually forces a page to be displayed in IE7 mode).  There's also the F12 tools, compatibility view settings, group policies, IE Enterprise mode, and more.

A better approach is to design the page to determine whether the current capabilities support your needs using things like feature detection, progressive enhancement, graceful fallback, etc.

There are things you can do to influence the decision, but there's always going to be some path, or feature, or workaround, update, or other factor that you didn't think of or predict.

What's the IE7 problem you're trying to solve?  Perhaps there's a different way to achieve the effect, one that doesn't rely on a feature unique to IE8.

Hoping to help...

-- Lance

P.S.  You might want to look at your smart quote settings, as the sample you posted uses "smart" quotes in the `meta` element.

Comment: That's how to set it up for earlier versions of desktop IE (and that certainly works), but unfortunately, it's not a guarantee or limit.  The user can use F12 tools to change the document mode, map the page into a zone where compatibility view is enabled by default, use alternate GPO settings, etc.

Further, it doesn't work in the Windows Store experience or MS Edge.  Ultimately, you verify that things are working the way you expect and might as well as approach the design with that in mind from the get-to.  

That my view.  YMMV.